# Qual a diferença entre OUTER APPLY e INNER JOIN em Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Qual a diferença entre `OUTER APPLY` e `INNER JOIN` no `Sql Server`?

Eu sei como o `LEFT/RIGHT/INNER JOIN` funciona porém me deparei com o `OUTER APPLY` eu dei uma lida mas não entendi por completo, parece ser um tipo de `INNER JOIN` aberto onde poderia fazer um subselect interno agindo como um `JOIN` normal. Seria isso? Ou tem mais coisas sobre?

Além disso como seria a performance comparando-os?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um OUTER APPLY o que vai fazer é devolver a nulo os campos nos quais não existe correspondência. Enquanto o Inner join não devolve, só devolve valores em que existe correspondência. Valores a nulo não são devolvidos.

Sem ser uma regra, utilizo muito operadores apply quando preciso de invocar uma chamada a uma função.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Poderia postar um exemplo de OUTER APPLY utilizando funcao? @Ivan

Comment: sim claro sem problemas,                                                                                             SELECT
    c.ContactID, c.FirstName, c.LastName, c.EmailAddress, c.Phone, x *
FROM Person.Contact c
OUTER APPLY [dbo].[ufnGetSalesInfo](c.ContactID) x
WHERE c.ContactID